# Sqlite ALTER TABLE - add column between existing columns?

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, alter-table

If I have a table with columns: a, b, c and later I do a ALTER TABLE command to add a new column "d", is it possible to add it between a and b for example, and not at the end?

I heard that the position of the columns affects performance.

Comment: The position of the columns is going to have basically zero impact on performance.

Comment: Posted an answer that may help over here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77898549/1077579

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to add a column between two existing columns with an ALTER TABLE statement in SQLite. This [works as designed](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html).

> The new column is always appended to the end of the list of existing
>   columns.

As far as I know, MySQL is the only SQL (ish) dbms that lets you [determine the placement of new columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html).

> To add a column at a specific position within a table row, use FIRST
>   or AFTER col_name. The default is to add the column last. You can also
>   use FIRST and AFTER in CHANGE or MODIFY operations to reorder columns
>   within a table.

But this isn't a feature I'd use regularly, so "as far as I know" isn't really very far.

Answer (score 1):

With every sql platform I've seen the only way to do this is to drop the table and re-create it.

However, I question if the position of the column affects performance... In what way would it, what operations are you doing that you think it will make a difference?

---

I will also note that dropping the table and recreating it is often not a heavy lift.  Making a backup of a table and restoring that table is easy on all major platforms so scripting a backup - drop - create - restore is an easy task for a competent DBA.

In fact I've done so often when users ask -- but I always find it a little silly.  The most often reason given is the tool of choice behaves nicer when the columns are created in a certain order.  (This was also @Jarad's reason below)  So this is a good lesson for tool makers, make your tool able to reorder columns (and remember it between runs) -- then everyone is happy.

Comment: I'm no professional programmer but I am insanely particular about grouping things in logical order. For me, although it makes no difference in performance where a column lives in a table, I prefer to have columns that are similar in function next to one another. For example, imagine you have a user-friendly name of a string and an internal name of a string (2 columns) in a table. It's advantageous to group them side-by-side when using a database browsing tool like DB Browser for SQLite. Rather than have to look at one side of the table, then horizontally scroll to the other, put them together.

Comment: @jarad of course I understand why someone would want the columns in a certain order, you do know that you can change the order of the columns in the select statement?

Answer (score 0):

I use the  DB.compileStatement:

```
    sql = DB.compileStatement("INSERT INTO tableX VALUES (?,?,?);
    sql.bindString(1,"value for column 1");
    sql.bindString(2,"value for column 2");
    sql.bindString(3,"value for column 3");
    sql.executeUpdateDelete();
```

So there will be a big difference if order of the columns is not correct.
Unfortunately adding columns at a specific position is not possible using ALTER TABLE, at least not in SQLite. (MySQL it is possible). Workaroud is recreating the table.. (and backup and restore data)