# Add new column after existing column in sqlite

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I need a SQL query which adds a new column after an existing column,
 so the column will be added in a specific order.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN  MiddleName varchar(50) AFTER Gender.
```

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Sqlite?

Comment: This is a [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q11).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. First, you could simply add a new column with the following:

```
ALTER TABLE {tableName} ADD COLUMN COLNew {type};
```

Second, and more complicatedly, but would actually put the column where you want it, would be to rename the table:

```
ALTER TABLE {tableName} RENAME TO TempOldTable;
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks Asif for prompt reply. I want to add new column with existing column. Suppose I have 4 column FirstName,LastName,Email,Gender,City. when i will execute ALTER TABLE {tableName} ADD COLUMN COLNew {type}; this query will add new column after City(LastColumn) but i will required after "Gender". This is my requirement.

Comment: @sureshchouksey It's not possible to add a column between two existing columns with an `ALTER TABLE` statement in SQLite. This [works as designed](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html). The new column is always appended to the end of the list of existing columns. To add a column at a specific position within a table row, use FIRST or AFTER col_name. The default is to add the column last. You can also use FIRST and AFTER in CHANGE or MODIFY operations to reorder columns within a table.

Comment: @sureshchouksey Probably duplicate this may helped you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477765/sqlite-alter-table-add-column-between-existing-columns).

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite doesnt have the `AFTER` keyword in `ALTER` like some other flavours do.

The only way to do this AFAIK is:

1. Turn foreign keys off if required. This prevents foreign key constraints from getting in your way.

```sql
PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF
```

2. Rename the table

```sql
ALTER TABLE {tableName} RENAME TO {tableName}_tmp;
```

3. Create the new table with the new column in the order you want

```sql
CREATE TABLE...
```

Also add any indexes you may have

4. Copy over the old table to the new table

```sql
INSERT INTO destination_table (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM source_table;
```

5. Delete the temp table

```sql
DROP TABLE {tableName}_tmp
```